# Need list of links and child page paths from a website using Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

Is it possible to get list of URL's / links available in a website by providing base URL as an input. Using nightwatch, if i pass base URL it should give all hyperlinks, child pages links etc. using Nightwatch. If its possible, how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Nightwatch is the right choice for what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can let us know what you want to do with the list of urls you fetch from the page?
You can set the URL via page object configuration and when the page loads (page.navigate()) you can return all link elements. Something like:

```
browser
  .elements("css selector", "a", result => {
     // Do something with 'result' that will contain all the elements matching "a"
  })
```

But I recommend you read more about Nightwatch to determine if that is the right tool for your needs.

More about Nightwatch: http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted

More about Page objects: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html